# Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(-1)^i \cos{\frac{(2i-1)\pi}{2n-2}}=-\frac12$ for even $n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> I want to prove
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n/2}(-1)^i \cos{\frac{(2i-1)\pi}{2n-2}}=-\frac12$$
> when $n$ is even.

I tried to solve it with Maclaurin series, but I can't.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, change $n/2$ to $n$.
$$ S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k \cos{\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{4n-2}}\\
= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \Re \exp\left(i\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{4n-2}\right )\\
=\Re \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \left[\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{4n-2}\right )\right]^k\exp\left(i\frac{-\pi}{4n-2}\right )\\
=\Re \left\{-\exp\left(i\frac{-\pi}{4n-2}\right )\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{4n-2}\right ) \frac{1-\left[-\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{4n-2}\right )\right]^n}{1+\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{4n-2}\right )}\right\} \\
$$
Taking the limit $n \to \infty$, it is pretty obvious that
$$
S_n \to -\Re \left\{\frac{1-\left[-\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{4n-2}\right )\right]^n}{2}\right\} \\
$$
Next, from the fact that $\frac{2n}{4n-2}\to \frac12$, we show that
$$
\left[-\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{4n-2}\right )\right]^n=-\exp\left(i\frac{2n\pi}{4n-2}\right ) \to -i,
$$
Hence its real part tends to zero.

From this we conclude that $S_n \to-1/2$

Comment: How is the denominator $4n-4$?

Comment: @PopularPower Well, for simplicity, I change $n/2$ to $n$.

Comment: But then the denominator should be $4n-2$?

Comment: @PopularPower Oh yes. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$(-1)^k\cos\left(\frac{2k-1}{2n-2}\pi\right)=\Re\left(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2n-2}}e^{ik\pi\left(\frac{2}{2n-2}+1\right)}\right).$$

Comment: @Ma Joad Great. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Ma Joad I came across this again and I think there is a mistake in your answer, maybe. Why $ [-\exp(i\frac{2\pi}{4n-2})]^n=-\exp(i\frac{2n\pi}{4n-2})$? We don't know $n$ is odd or is even. So the answer of the limit of it ($-i$) is not correct.